# Embedded Youtube iFrame FullScreen button is not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, fullscreen

I embedded the code using the Youtube recommended method, but the full screen function was not working at all. So I tried adding mozallowfullscreen, webkitallowfullscreen etc. but still no luck.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/v/16N8Zhhhins?rel=0&hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" id="listing_detail_youtube" mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
```

In case it helps.. the doctype etc. at the beginning are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="overflow-x: hidden">
<head>
```

CSS on that iFrame, if it helps...

```
#listing_detail_youtube {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

But. When I copy-paste the video iframe URL alone and open it on Firefox, Chrome etc. the full screen still does not work, so I suspect the issue is somewhere within the `<iframe>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1gI_HGDgG7c" allowfullscreen="" height="315" width="460"></iframe>
```

use https://www.youtube.com/embed/-video_id-

Answer (score -1):

I just solved this problem by using the new embed command for html5 instead of iframes.  For an example, check this page:

http://www.flexxifinger.com/videoemb.php

Hope this helps...